# How to access an attribute inside the simulation zone from the previous frame?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

So I am trying to simulate a particle under gravity, specifically trying to use a verlet numerical method. All I want for now is to have the particle move under constant acceleration downward. The formula for the method is X(n+1) = Xn + (Xn - X(n-1)) + aΔt^2.

Basically to compute the new position, I need to add the current position minus the old position to the current position and then add acceleration times timestep squared. For that i would need the position for the last frame. But im not really sure on how i could access that/if its even possible inside simulation nodes.

Im thinking it may be possible by storing attributes maybe? But am confused on how it should look inside nodes, specifically how i lay it out in the simulation zone. Hope someone can help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct full answer to your question, but with understanding the node tree you should easily be able to do what you want:

[image]

Just store the "old position as named attribute". Then in the loop do "something" with the old Pos and your current position, then save the old Pos as your new position within the loop.